# Retorno de json_encode tira a ordem do asort()

Tags: php, jquery, classificação

O método `asort()` é usado para ordenar arrays, sem perder o índice.
Faço a ordenação, tanto na busca do SQL quanto no array. Porém, ao enviar os dados via JSON (usando `json_encode`), ele reordena as chaves.

### Exemplo de Array, ordenado, montado com cidades e meu índice na tabela:

```
Array
(
    [4550] => AGUA BRANCA
    [8339] => ANADIA
    [3292] => ARAPIRACA
    [7509] => ATALAIA
    [21265] => BARRA DE SANTO ANTONIO
    [9109] => BARRA DE SAO MIGUEL
    ...
```

### Exemplo de JSON, mostrado no PREVIEW do navegador (ainda ordenado):

```
"cidades":{"4550":"AGUA BRANCA","8339":"ANADIA","3292":"ARAPIRACA","7509":"ATALAIA","21265":"BARRA DE SANTO ANTONIO","9109":"BARRA DE SAO MIGUEL","6127"
```

### Exemplo de Options, gerados via ajax, dos dados:

```
<option value="314">MACEIO</option>
<option value="872">PILAR</option>
<option value="1145">UNIAO DOS PALMARES</option>
<option value="1432">RIO LARGO</option>
<option value="1647">MARIBONDO</option>
<option value="1648">SAO MIGUEL DOS CAMPOS</option>
<option value="1845">PARIPUEIRA</option>
```

Na recepção do `ajax`, não peço pra ordenar por chave, que é o que acontece. A geração do meu `SELECT` é simplesmente:

```
$.each(data.cidades,function(k,v){
    options += "<option value='"+k+"'>"+v+"</option>";
});
$("#consumidor_cidade").html(options);
```

Comment: Tenta dar um `console.log(v)` dentro do each pra ver se ele está ordenado

Comment: Acredito que o seu problema seja relacionado a forma como o javascript armazena internamente seus objetos. Acredito que não tenha como você garantir a ordenação dos registros através de propriedades. Por este motivo, sugiro que mude seu json para ser um array ao invés de um objeto

Comment: @jlHertel Esse foi o problema: A necessidade de se enviar um Objeto. Antes era como array, sem índice. Mas houve a necessidade de se gravar índice no retorno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema não é no `json_encode`, como você mesmo mostrou no preview vem na ordem correta.

O problema acontece pois no JavaScript apenas arrays tem ordem definida, mas não possuem indices associativos, então ao fazer um `json_encode` o PHP gera um JSON no formato de objeto - que não possui ordem definida.

O que você pode fazer é enviar um atributo a mais na lista com a ordem, ou deixar o índice do array sequencial na ordem que você quer exibir e salvar o id e o nome numa estrutura interna.

Uma estrutura nesse estilo ira manter a ordem.

```
$arr = [
  ['codigo'=>'4550', 'nome'=>'AGUA BRANCA'],
  ['codigo'=>'8339', 'nome'=>'ANADIA']
]
```

Ou então especificando a ordem:

```
$arr = [
  ['codigo'=>'4550', 'nome'=>'AGUA BRANCA', 'order'=>0],
  ['codigo'=>'8339', 'nome'=>'ANADIA', 'order'=>1]
]
```

## EDIÇÃO DO REQUISITANTE PARA MOSTRA DA RESPOSTA CERTA

Na montagem do meu array, foi feita dessa forma:

```
while ($resultado = pg_fetch_object($res)) {
    $cidades[] = array("cidade_id" => $resultado->cidade, "cidade_nome" => $resultado->cidade_nome);
}
/*envio*/
return json_encode(array("ok"=>true,"cidades" => $cidades));
```

E a montagem pelo `jQuery` foi descrita na resposta do Hertel.

Comment: Até editei o título para "retirar a culpa" do `json_encode`, mas como disse no comentário da pergunta, na mudança da necessidade do recebimento da informação, aconteceu essa desordem.

Comment: @WilliamAparecidoBrandino como coloquei na resposta, o javaScript não mantém essa ordem, você vai ter que enviar esses dados em uma estrutura que tenha explicito essa ordem para poder remontar a listagem.

Comment: @WilliamAparecidoBrandino adicionei um exemplo de uma estrutura para manter a ordem.

Answer (score 1):

Como o @Marcos já comentou, seu problema não está na função `json_encode`, mas sim no modo como as propriedades são indexadas internamente pela engine do `Javascript`.

Uma solução alternativa ao seu problema é utilizar um array e ter vários objetos ordenados dentro dele:

```
<?php
$array = [
   [
     "indice" => 4550,
     "nome"   => "AGUA BRANCA"
   ],
   [
     "indice" => 8339,
     "nome"   => "ANADIA"
   ]
];
```

E no javascript faça:

```
$.each(data.cidades,function(k,v){
    options += "<option value='"+v.indice+"'>"+v.nome+"</option>";
});
$("#consumidor_cidade").html(options);
```

Comment: Sim, montei aqui e agora funcionou. Tive que fazer o que vocês disseram. Como os dois responderam a mesma coisa, não sei em quem eu marco a resposta certa.

Comment: @WilliamAparecidoBrandino, o importante é que seu problema foi solucionado. Pode marcar qualquer um dos dois que está ótimo.